# how to add extra fields in the website using flask fields.FieldList

Tags: python, html, forms, templates, flask

I want the user to be able to add or remove fields in the website,  I am using flask and fields.FieldList

I know how to do that directly with javascript only clone the field section of the DOM and rename the attributes like name, id etc...  is there an easy way to do it with flask/ flask forms?  I want to achieve something like in the picture (doesn't have to be in that layout, I really don't care the layout since I can move it later on)
[image: I want a new render of adding and removing fields]
and then been able to pass it to the back end and been recognize by the flask forms.

thanks in advance, I appreciate it =)

This are my forms:

```
class AddressForm(FlaskForm):
addr = fields.StringField("address")

class MainForm(FlaskForm):
addressees = fields.FieldList(fields.FormField(AddressForm), min_entries=1, validators=[DataRequired()])
```

This is my view:

```
    def addressees_create():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MainForm()
            if form.validate():
                print("is validate")
            else:
                print("was not validate")

            if form.validate_on_submit():
                print("the form was validated on submit")
            else:
                print("was not validated on submit")

            print(form.data)
            addressees = form.data["addressees"]
            for address in addressees:
                print("\t"+str(address))

            return render_template("my/template.html",form=form)
        else:
            form = MainForm()
            return render_template("my/template.html", form=form)
```

This is the template:

```
    <div>
        {% for item in form.addressees %}
            {{ item.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ item.addr }}
        {% endfor %}

        <div style="color: red;">
            {% for error in form.addressees.errors %}
                <span>{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. Here is my solution

```
class CreatePollForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    options = FieldList(StringField())
    submit = SubmitField('Create')


<ul id="options">
    <li>
        <label for="options-0">Options-0</label>
        <input id="options-0" name="options-0" type="text" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="options-1">
            Options-1
        </label>
        <input id="options-1" name="options-1" type="text" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="options-2">Options-2</label>
        <input id="options-2" name="options-2" type="text" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="options-3">Options-3</label>
        <input id="options-3" name="options-3" type="text" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="options-4">Options-4</label>
        <input id="options-4" name="options-4" type="text" value="">
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can refer to this data like this:

```
form = CreatePollForm()
print(form.options.data)
```